# how to reset password in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

i'm following tutorials trying to reset my password but it doesn't to even open the view in the browser , that's my route :

```
Route::get('password/email','Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
Route::post('password/email','Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');

Route::get('password/reset/{token}','Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
Route::post('password/reset','Auth\PasswordController@postReset');
```

and that's my view

```
<form  method="post" action="password/email" enctype="multipart/form-code">
     {!! csrf_field() !!}
     <table class="table" style="width:50%; margin:0 auto;">

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h1 class="well text-center">Reset Password Form</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            Email:<input type="email" name="email" value="{{old('email')}}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send Password</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>

     </form>
```

can anyone help me please ?

Comment: what is the error log that you see?

Comment: Are you editing the view in `resources/views/auth/passwords/email.blade.php`? Also the correct form enctype is `multipart/form-data`, though only if you want to upload a file with your form.

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: @VishalSh that's the error i had

Comment: @tjbp i don't edit anything that's the view exactly in the tutorial and the view name is password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use a tutorial, just run `php artisan make:auth` to create routes, controllers and views in your application, as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication). Afterwards you can edit the controllers and views as you see fit.

Comment: you mean i run this command and it will automatically generate the authentication methods and views ?

Comment: @MohamedElbiheiry yup.

Answer (score 0):

is your views name the same as the view::make in the PasswordController ?